# ASP.NET WebAPI DbContext - Unable to create an object of type / No database provider has been configured

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've been following this tutorial: [YT Tutorial (starts at my issue)](https://youtu.be/S5dzfuh3t8U?t=810) with the exception that I'm on .NET6. When I add a migration The two errors I can get are either:

- No database provider has been configured for this DbContext (...)
- Unable to create an object of type 'PmrDbContext'. (...) <- this happens if I leave out a default constructor

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
var app = builder.Build();
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PmrDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

PmrDbContext.cs:

```
public class PmrDbContext : DbContext
{
    // default constructor there - one or the other error

    public PmrDbContext(DbContextOptions<PmrDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

ConnectionString:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DevConnection": "Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=PMRHomeDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
 }
```

Do I need to create a DB first? Is this not a **code-first EF** solution?

Comment: If you don't have a DB yet you need to do a first migration which will create it for you.

Comment: Here's a step by step explanation: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-new-database-using-code-first-in-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change Services after Build(), so I moved the AddDbContext before it - also leaving out the default constructor in my DbContext class.

```
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PmrDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
var app = builder.Build();
```

I ran the project and it was working. Also the Add-Migration also worked this way.